# I am stuck at alarm selecting days in iphone application?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want a small iOS application for alarm. Once i select the particular day and time, notification should be raise.

If i select all days, everyday that alarm should be raise. Would you please help me on this application and send me if you have the code already.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *datePickerDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:datePickerDate];
NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:datePickerDate];

NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
[dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
[dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];

[dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour] ];
[dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
[dateComps setSecond:00];

NSDate *fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
//NSLog(@"%@",fireDate);
localNotif.fireDate = fireDate;
localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
//localNotif.repeatInterval = 1.0;
localNotif.alertAction = @"Alarm";
//NSLog(@"%@",alarmId);

//for alarm once
if ([alarm.repeat_mode_id intValue] == 0) {


} else if([alarm.repeat_mode_id intValue] == 1) { //for alarm every day
    localNotif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
}
localNotif.alertBody = alarm.alarm_label;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use the following steps to Create Alarm everyday.

1. You Create Alarm and Store This Alarm in NSUSerDefaults or Database.
   Ex:FireDate: 12-11-2013 10.30AM
2. Once Alarm Is Done. That is Alarm received, Update one day in Already stored Date value.

   ```
   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0)
   {
        UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
         if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
       {
            // The Alarm Received The Pointer come to This.
       }
   else
   {
        // You click notification. the pointer come in else condition
    NSDate *alerm_time_str=[alarmData valueForKey:@"FireDate"];


    NSDate *fire_date;

           if ([alerm_time_str timeIntervalSinceNow] < 0.0) {

               NSLog(@"Date is Passed");

               int daysToAdd = 1;
               NSDate *newDate1 = [alerm_time_str dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToAdd];
               fire_date=newDate1;

           }
           else
           {
               fire_date=alerm_time_str;
           }
   ```

   }

If any clarification let me.